# Construir um prédio "3D" com HTML, CSS e JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como eu posso reproduzir a imagem abaixo utilizando HTML, CSS e JS (talvez imagens)? O números de "andares" é imprevisível e cada "andar" deve ser "clicável", um `<a href="#"></a>`, ou algo assim.

[image: prédio]

É possível fazer?

Comment: Possível até seria, talvez utilizando um [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas), ou [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction), com auxilio de alguma biblioteca (talvez [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)), mas acredito que seria algum bem complicado e trabalhoso, há real necessidade de 3D?

Comment: Eu coloquei o 3D entre aspas por isto. Eu preciso apenas desta impressão de 3D, com esta dobra em um dos vértices. Canvas e SVG provavelmente não terão suporte no IE9, mas eu pesquisarei. Obrigado, @Fernando

Comment: A fachada da frente é trivial (já que é retangular), mas as do lado iriam demandar algum ajuste (talvez uma transformação CSS3 seria suficiente, não precisaria de canvas). O que você pretende colocar nesse espaço? Imagens/HTML customizado, ou todo andar é igual, só muda o texto?

Comment: @erickalves05, o máximo que consegui, chegar usando somente html e css3, foi [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/nx5mgz4r/). Mas ta mais para um menu do que prédio. Hehe. Talvez SVG, com CSS3 seja o melhor caminho.

Comment: @mgibsonbr só mudaria o texto mesmo.

Comment: @Fernando, obrigado pela ajuda. Já me levou a conhecer mais sobre o canvas e SVG. Vou continuar me aprofundado.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pode-se fazer o que você quer usando apenas HTML e transformações CSS3. [Essa ferramenta](http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html) serve como um ponto de partida, para você experimentar com as opções disponíveis, mas para um maior controle é melhor fazer manualmente. A forma de usar é:

1. Coloque no seu CSS a propriedade `transform`, seguida de uma ou mais operações de transformação;
2. A operação <del>`skew`</del> (nota: [não-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew)) serve para inclinar o elemento, e a operação `translate` o desloca; ambas as operações ocorrem **na horizontal**;

   - Nota: existem variantes `skewX` e `skewY`, `tranlateX` e `translateY`, etc.
3. A operação `rotate` rotaciona o elemento; qualquer operação subsequente já leva em consideração o elemento rotacionado, de modo que se você quer deslocar um elemento verticalmente, por exemplo, gire-o 90 graus, desloque-o, e gire-o 90 graus novamente (se for o caso).
4. A operação `scale` aumenta/diminui o elemento em escala.

Essas são algumas operações simples. Para uma lista mais completa, ver [essa documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Note que nem todas elas podem ser suportadas por todos os browsers, e alguns deles exigem um prefixo (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-`) antes de `transform`, já que essa propriedade ainda não foi totalmente padronizada.

Abaixo está um exemplo bem tosco do que pode ser feito. Ele inclina o topo; desloca a frente; desloca, gira, escala, inclina, e desloca novamente os lados, de modo a colocá-los no lugar adequado. Os elementos são HTML comum, de modo que você pode colocar ali o que quiser. Tanto a frente quanto o lado é clicável, e coloquei também um efeito `hover` para mudar a cor do andar sob o mouse.

```css
#topo {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 102px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  margin: 20px;
}

#andares {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

#andares .frente {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-54px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-54px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-54px);
  -o-transform: translate(-54px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-54px);
  margin-top: -18px;
}

#andares li:hover .frente {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#andares .lado {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
  transform: translate(52px) rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skewX(45deg) translate(-27px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(52px) rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skewX(45deg) translate(-27px);
  -moz-transform: translate(52px) rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skewX(45deg) translate(-27px);
  -o-transform: translate(52px) rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skewX(45deg) translate(-27px);
  -ms-transform: translate(52px) rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skewX(45deg) translate(-27px);
}

#andares li:hover .lado {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="topo"></div>
<ul id="andares">
  <li><a href="http://google.com"><div class="frente">Google</div><div class="lado"></div></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://facebook.com"><div class="frente">Facebook</div><div class="lado"></div></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><div class="frente">Twitter</div><div class="lado"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Eita, né que conseguiu mesmo, e sem `svg`, ficou bacana (comparado ao [meu](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/nx5mgz4r/)), e ótima explicação. +1